# Selected row not returned correctly in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a data table built with Primefaces. It contains a list of "Person" . "Person" is a Java class with only 1 String attribute - "name", has constructor with no parameters, constructor with 1 String parameter, getter and setter for "name". First column of the table contains the person name. Second column contains a commandButton. By pressing it, is is opened a dialog. In this dialog I want to see the name of the selected person. 
The JSF page is this:

```
<h:form id="personForm" prependId="false">
<p:dataTable id="personEntitiesTable" var="pers" value="#{personView.persons}">
    <p:column headerText="Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{pers.name}" />
    </p:column>          
    <p:column headerText="">             
        <p:commandButton value="Details" type="button" onclick="PF('personDetails').show();" />
        <p:dialog header="Person details" widgetVar="personDetails" modal="true" height="150" >     
            Selected person is "#{pers.name}"
        </p:dialog>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The managedBean for the table is:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public classPersonView implements Serializable {
    private List<Person> persons;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person("John"));
        persons.add(new Person("Mary"));
        persons.add(new Person("James"));
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

So, if I press the button "Details" for the user "Mary", it is opened a dialog where I expect to see the message "Selected person is Mary". The problem is no matter the row where I press the button "Details", the message inside dialog is "Selected person is James" . "James" is the last person from the list.

Comment: For n persons you get n dialogs rendered each having the wiedgetVar `personDetails`. Obviously the last one wins. WidgetVars must be unique on the rendered HTML document.

Comment: And you are not engaging the selection mechanism of the dataTable at all. Your Title and text suggests you are trying to achive this: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: 1: put the dialog outside the datatable, 2: this is a duplicate of some other question in the widgetvar not being unique and the last one wins here. Let  me find the duplicate

Answer (score -1):

As the dialog was declared inside datatable column, JSF will generate one dialog for each table row. Since all of them use same widgetVar, the last one will be called when execute `PF('personDetails').show()`.

Try this way:

1. Put your dialog outside of datatable.
2. Your dialog must use a managed bean property (`personView.selectedPerson`).
3. Details button must set `personView.selectedPerson` with `pers` variable:
   `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{personView.selectedPerson}" value="#{pers}"/>`
   and update the dialog content.

Comment: That is an 'improvement' but does not explain the cause of the problem OP is experiencing...

Comment: I added the attribute in PersonView, and for the p:commandButton tag I added also update=":personDetails" . The problem still persists.

Comment: Are you sure you declared your dialog out of datatable? Otherwise JSF will generate one dialog for each table row. Since all of them use same widgetVar, the last one will be called when execute `PF('personDetails').show()`.

Comment: @CatalinVladu checks if you button is like that: <p:commandButton value="Details" type="button" onclick="PF('personDetails').show();" ><f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{personView.selectedPerson}" value="#{pers}"/></p:commandButton>

Comment: I applied what says here, and works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322572/selected-row-not-returned-correctly-in-pdatatable/58323669?noredirect=1#comment103051247_58323669

Comment: Why my answer was downvoted? This solution is exactly what the Primefaces Showcase suggests and I've been using in my projects.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I checked the solution presented in the link. "widgetvar" was the problem.